# Sending text via an HTTP POST request

Tags: python, http, curl, post, endpoint

There is an app endpoint on a remote expecting text via HTTP POST.

Can this be done by simply sending a text file?
specifically, I am using curl:

```
curl -X POST -d lines.txt http://theserver.com/theendpoint
```

Or must I send the text as a stream, using, let's say, a Python script? I tried this:

```
def send_to_server(text):
    url = 'http://theserver.com/theendpoint'
    headers = {'content-type': 'text/plain'}
    r = requests.post(url=url, data=text, headers=headers)
    return r
```

where `text` is created by:

```
output = io.StringIO()
output.write( some_function() ) # getting some text from a different function 
text = output.getvalue()
```

In other words - is the app on the server getting what it expects in both ways?

Answer (score 1):

`-d` passes the string from command line as the body, `-d @` passes the contents of the file given in the command line as the body.

You want the latter:

```
curl -X POST -d @lines.txt http://theserver.com/theendpoint
```

Comment: I am trying to POST a text file, though. Which should be used?

Comment: Which what? Have you looked at the man page and/or tried curl's options?

Comment: Which of the two things you mentioned: "data string" (what is that?) and "data file". I am trying to send a text file.